# Programatically locking the device not working even after providing Device Admin Access

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am trying to build an Flutter App in which I need to lock the device after a timer hits zero. To use the locking functionality, I am using Flutter's provided MethodChannel to use `DevicePolicyService`'s `lockNow` function.
Now, the problem here is, even on providing all permissions, it is still now enabled for my app. I am using Xiaomi's Redmi Note 7 Pro with developer mode ON.
Here is my `main.dart`

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/lock');
  String errorMessage = '';
  Future<void> _getBatteryLevel() async {
    String batteryLevel;
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('lockDevice');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      errorMessage = 'Failed to get battery level: ${e.message}';
    }
    setState(() {
      errorMessage = errorMessage;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _getBatteryLevel,
              child: const Text('Get Battery Level')),
          Text(errorMessage)
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

and `MainActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.batterylevel

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/lock"
    private lateinit var devicePolicyManager: DevicePolicyManager
    private lateinit var componentName: ComponentName

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        // Initialize DevicePolicyManager and ComponentName
        devicePolicyManager = getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
        componentName = ComponentName(this, MyDeviceAdminReceiver::class.java)

        // Set up MethodChannel to handle locking device
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "lockDevice") {
                if (devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName)) {
                    devicePolicyManager.lockNow()
                    result.success("Device locked")
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enable device admin
                    val intent = Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN)
                    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, componentName)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    result.error("DEVICE_ADMIN_NOT_ENABLED", "Device admin not enabled", null)
                }
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:label="Device Admin Sample">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver_info" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

`device_admin_receiver_info.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin>
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Even when not enabling the access through the App, and going through the device's settings, after agreeing to the risks, It still doesn't get enabled and fails without any warnings.

Any help would be highly appreciated.